# Keycloak is missing port in OpenID config response

Tags: keycloak

These one seems odd. When I fetch the OpenID config via Postman or in the browser, I get a valid config response.

For example a GET via Postman or in the browser to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

returns the endpoint including the port 8080 correctly:

```
{
 snip
"jwks_uri": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs"
snip
}
```

However, fetching the from the very same host, target, port, scheme (http) in my C++ application returns the confi endpoints all without a port (e.g. 8080 is missing)

```
{
 snip
"jwks_uri":"http://127.0.0.1/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs"
snip
}
```

I do not see any issue in my C++ client code, I'm not sure what's making the difference at all. For completeness, this is the C++ code I'm using next to actual values when sending the request, though that should not really be a matter of programming language used:

```
    req_.version(version); // HTTP 1.1
    req_.method(method); // GET
    req_.target(target); // /auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration
    req_.set(http::field::host, host); // 127.0.0.1
    static const std::string agent = app.myAgent(); 
    req_.set(http::field::user_agent, agent);
    req_.set(http::field::content_type, contentType); // application/json
```

I have two questions here:

1) What causes Keycloak not to add the port to the endpoints? And how to workaround it?

2) What's making the difference between the calls? This should be a vanilla GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. According to the HTTP spec the port must be included in the host name if it's not a default name:

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23

That resolved the issue. Though, my opinion is it should be fixed in Keycloak as well. I would expect static URLs and not something that changes depending on your request. For an example, you could set host to localhost during request and it will return "localhost" in the config, set it to 127.0.0.1 and it will return that. What will it return for an actual IP when queried locally, but the server has a public IP? I didn't try that but it seems odd enough.

Comment: Hi, May be you could find some answers to your question in keycloak documentation related to hostname management : https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#hostname